# NPE when stubbing a mock's method with Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

I am trying to test a repository `ExpensesRepository`

```kotlin
class ExpensesRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val store: DataStore
) : AbstractRepository<Expense> {

    override fun get(offset: Int, limit: Int): List<Expense?> =
        store.getAll(offset, limit)

    override fun get(key: String): Expense? = store.getOne(key = key)

    override fun create(input: Expense) =
        store.create(key = input.key, element = input)


    override fun delete(key: String) = store.remove(key = key)

    override fun update(
        key: String,
        update: Expense
    ): Expense =
        store.update(key = key, element = update)

    override fun removeAll() = store.flush()
}
```

In the test suite I have mocked the `store` parameter using mockito, then I stubbed that mock's method `getOne(String)` to return an expense object from my fixtures.

Here is my test suite

```kotlin
class ExpensesRepositoryTest {

    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var repository: ExpensesRepository
    private val dataStore = mock<DataStore>()
    private val expense = Expense(
        "key",
        1,
        "name",
        "date",
        12.12
    )

    private val expenseList = listOf(
        expense,
        expense,
        expense
    )

    private val dummyKey = "expense_key"

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        repository = ExpensesRepository(dataStore)
    }

    @Test
    fun `should get an item with existing key`() {
        whenever(dataStore.getOne<Expense>(dummyKey)).thenReturn(expense)
        val result = repository.get(dummyKey)
        verify(dataStore, Times(1)).getOne<Expense>(dummyKey)
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expense)
    }
}
```

When I run the test it fails cuz of `NullPointerException` and that's when the `DataStore` calls the function `getOne(String)` that I supposedly stubbed earlier. In case it helps here is the `DataStore` class

```kotlin
class DataStore(val store: Persistence, val gson: Gson) {

    inline fun <reified R : Persistable> getAll(
        offset: Int,
        limit: Int
    ): List<R?> =
        store.get(offset, limit).map { it.maybeMapTo<R>(mapper = gson) }

    inline fun <reified R : Persistable> getOne(key: String): R? =
        store.get(key).maybeMapTo<R>(mapper = gson)

    fun create(key: String, element: Persistable) {
        store.create(
            key = key,
            element = when (store) {
                is JsonBased -> gson.toJson(element)
                else -> element
            }
        )
    }

    inline fun <reified R : Persistable> update(
        key: String,
        element: R
    ): R {
        return store.update(key, element) as R
    }

    fun remove(key: String) {
        store.remove(key)
    }

    fun flush() {
        store.flush()
    }
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: why not mocking `Persistence` class and inject it in `DataStore` ?

Comment: in that case DataStore becomes a real instance and not a mock. Ideally only the class under test should be the real object. So If you do that you will have to spy on DataStore which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are out of luck: inline functions are not mockable.

Comment: kotlin inline functions are translated as `final` functions in java. According to Mockito new release mocking final classes and methods is now possible. https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final
this doesn't seem to work for me in android studio, does it work for you?

Comment: @Aouledlssa No, it won't work. Your unit test is written in kotlin, so inline functions get inlined by the compiler (the translated fiinal functions are not used). You could try writing the test in java, but I'm not sure if it would work.

Comment: that is a sad thing tho. Do you know of any other mocking framework that supports inline functions?